# Webpack import node_module in css as global

Tags: webpack, webpack-style-loader, css-modules, css-loader

I used to import directly in javascript like
`import '!style-loader!css-loader!../../node_modules/react-soundplayer/styles/buttons.css'` but its too ugly and I dont like it

In my react component, I want to specify a css-module
`import style from './style/App.css'`, and in `App.css`, I have

```
:global (@import '~react-soundplayer/styles/buttons.css');
```

The :global is not working, it just prints ":global (@import '~basscss/css/basscss.css');" in a style element in HTML head after webpack.

I need a way to import node_modules stuff in my .css as **global css and preserve the original class name** (without applying css-loader `localIdentName: '[path][name]__[local]'`)

My webpack.config is

```
const path = require('path');

const package = require('./package.json');

const PATHS = {
    src: path.join(__dirname, './src'),
    public: path.join(__dirname, './public')
};

var config = {
    entry: { 
        app: [ 'babel-polyfill', path.resolve(PATHS.src, 'index.js') ] 
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(PATHS.public),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.resolve(PATHS.public),
        port: 3000,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        proxy: {
            '/api/**': {
            target: 'http://localhost:5000',
            changeOrigin: true
            }
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            use: [
                { 
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
            ],
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'style-loader',
                    options: { singleton: true }
                },
                {
                    loader: 'css-loader',
                    options: { 
                        modules: true,
                        camelCase: 'dashes',
                        localIdentName: '[path][name]__[local]' 
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
        ]
    }
};
module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution

I made a `node_modules.css` which includes regular css from node_modules and globals:

```
@import '~basscss/css/basscss.css';
@import '~react-soundplayer/styles/buttons.css';
@import '~react-soundplayer/styles/progress.css';
@import '~react-soundplayer/styles/volume.css';

/* OVERRIDE NODE_MODULES (:global() and !important not required) */
/* basscss */
svg {
    fill: var(--description-color);
    stroke: var(--description-color);
}

.red {
  color: var(--description-color);
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.p2 {
  text-align: left;
}

/* react-soundplayer */
.sb-soundplayer-progress-container {
  background-color: var(--title-color);
}

.sb-soundplayer-progress-inner {
  background-color: var(--description-color);
}

.sb-soundplayer-volume-range::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
background: var(--title-color);
}

.sb-soundplayer-volume-range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background: var(--description-color);
}
```

in `webpack.config.js`, I added another module rule that includes css from node_modules through the style and css loader, except css loader is configured to not use modules:

```
...
module: {
    rules: [
        {   
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'style-loader',
                    options: { singleton: true }
                },
                {
                    loader: 'css-loader',
                    options: { 
                        modules: false
                    }
                }
            ],
            include: [
                /(node_modules|bower_components)/, 
                path.resolve(PATHS.src, 'style/node_modules.css')
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'style-loader',
                    options: { singleton: true }
                },
                {
                    loader: 'css-loader',
                    options: { 
                        modules: true,
                        camelCase: 'dashes',
                        localIdentName: '[path][name]__[local]' 
                    }
                }
            ],
            exclude: [
                /(node_modules|bower_components)/, 
                path.resolve(PATHS.src, 'style/node_modules.css')
            ]
        }
    ]
}
...
```

including it in other css files doesnt work because the webpack preprocesses it as a css-module

```
/* css */
@import url('./node_modules.css');
...
/* other css classes*/
```

it works only when imported directly into javascript

```
// javascript    
import './style/node_modules.css'
...
```